# How to configure react, jsx, and babel in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, reactjs, babeljs

I want to start learning ReactJs with jsx and Babel. My editor is Visual Studio Code. I need to config them to work together in VSCode, but after search in Google and StackOverFlow, I found dispersed contents for different frameworks and platforms. Is there any resource to learn step by step configuration and using react in VSCode?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found babel-standalone in [GitHub](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone) .

> babel-standalone is a standalone build of Babel for use in non-Node.js environments, including browsers. It's bundled with all the standard Babel plugins and presets, and a build of babili (babel-minify) is optionally available too.

With babel-standalone we can compile out JavaScript files with jsx format in browser. Easy installation and usage.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (same one I have): "Is there any resource to learn step by step configuration and using react in VSCode?" not, "where can I download Babel."